# regex parsing issue ecmascript

Tags: javascript, regex, web-scraping, ecmascript-6

Can someone please help me to addapt this regex :

```
var re = /<a href='([\s\S]*?)'([\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?<img src='([\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?<\/a>/g;
 var match = re.exec(doc);
```

I need to be able extract links only links :

```
while (match) {var url = BASE_URL + match[1]; page.appendItem(plugin.getDescriptor().id + ':index:' + escape(BASE_URL + match[1]), 'video', {
                title: new showtime.RichText(match[2]),
                icon: checkUrl(match[3])
            });

            match = re.exec(doc);
        }
```

I was trying to puzzle it out with 2 variables, but it is not working...

```
var b = "(id=\d*)'";

var a = "<a href='/details.php[*?]";
```

**target string was like this originally :**

```
<a href='/details.php?id=1578358' title='Аритмия / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://picplus.ru/img/1711/15/05d0f570.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?id=1557197' title='Выстрел в пустоту (Главарь) / Shot Caller / 2017 / ПМ / BDRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/9/7/1557197.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?id=1564178' title='Бабушка лёгкого поведения / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/7/8/1564178.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?id=1570558' title='Напарник / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/5/8/1570558.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?id=1579515' title='Мадам / Madame / 2017 / ДБ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://picplus.ru/img/1711/22/d03ca6e5.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?id=1571565' title='Про любовь. Только для взрослых / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/6/5/1571565.jpg' alt=''></a>
```

Now they changed the code and regex doesn't work anymore....

```
</div><div class='mn1_content'><div class=pad0x0x5x0><ul class=lis><li class=mn><a href="/top.php" title="Топ раздач">Топ раздач</a></li><li><a href="/top.php?w=1" title="Топ раздач недели">Топ раздач недели</a></li><li><a href="/top.php?w=2" title="Топ раздач месяца">Топ раздач месяца</a></li><li><a href="/top.php?w=3" title="Топ раздач 3 месяца">Топ раздач 3 месяца</a></li></ul></div><div class='bx1 stable'><a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1563719' title='Пираты Карибского моря: Мертвецы не рассказывают сказки / Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales / 2017 / ДБ / HDRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/1/9/1563719.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1578358' title='Аритмия / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://picplus.ru/img/1711/15/05d0f570.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1557197' title='Выстрел в пустоту (Главарь) / Shot Caller / 2017 / ПМ / BDRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/9/7/1557197.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1564178' title='Бабушка лёгкого поведения / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/7/8/1564178.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1570558' title='Напарник / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/5/8/1570558.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1579515' title='Мадам / Madame / 2017 / ДБ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://picplus.ru/img/1711/22/d03ca6e5.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1571565' title='Про любовь. Только для взрослых / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/6/5/1571565.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1576347' title='Троцкий (1-8 серии из 8) / 2017 / РУ / SATRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/4/7/1576347.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1569291' title='Оно / It / 2017 / ПМ / HDTVRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/9/1/1569291.jpg' alt=''></a>
```

What I need is a regex thats take the link :

```
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1578358'
```

and keeps only this: /details.php?id=1578358 .  remove 14 chars from "?" till "id" and all numbers following "="

Please excuse me for my english and thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you just turn it into HTML and use DOM methods!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you want to keep on using the matches in you code, but you want to remove data like this `SbI135km9&amp;` from `match[1]` which would look like:

`/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1563719`.

If this is the case, you could use your original regex and replace the data of `match[1]` in your while loop.

To match the data you want to replace you could take any word character one or more times `\w+` and then `$amp;` and replace it with an empty string

For example:

`var m1 = match[1].replace(/\w+&amp;/, "");`

Answer (score 0):

Simply break your regex for the `href` into 2 pieces: the first part you're interested in, the second part probably not.

```
<a href='([^\?]*)(.*?)'(?:[\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?<img src='([\s\S]*?)'[\s\S]*?<\/a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do

```
let re = /(^.+\')(\/[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\?)(.{0,})(id=[0-9]+)(.+)/gi
let link = "<a href='/details.php?asdasd;id=1578358&asdasdasd'"
let replaced = link.replace(re, "$2$4");
```

Small explanation - this will gonna save the filename with extension and id with numbers, no matter what is there besides them.

Answer (score 0):

### Brief

This is more of a job for a DOM parser, but, assuming this is a subset of **known** DOM elements, you can use the following regex and code to match the links.

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/yA5lpa/1)
**Note**: I have the link above set to PCRE regex since the JavaScript flavour doesn't display matches; it works just the same in both engines.

```
<a href='([^']*)'[\s\S]*?'[\s\S]*?<img src='([^']*)'[\s\S]*?<\/a>
```

#### Usage

```js
var doc = `
</div><div class='mn1_content'><div class=pad0x0x5x0><ul class=lis><li class=mn><a href="/top.php" title="Топ раздач">Топ раздач</a></li><li><a href="/top.php?w=1" title="Топ раздач недели">Топ раздач недели</a></li><li><a href="/top.php?w=2" title="Топ раздач месяца">Топ раздач месяца</a></li><li><a href="/top.php?w=3" title="Топ раздач 3 месяца">Топ раздач 3 месяца</a></li></ul></div><div class='bx1 stable'><a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1563719' title='Пираты Карибского моря: Мертвецы не рассказывают сказки / Pirates of the Caribbean: Dead Men Tell No Tales / 2017 / ДБ / HDRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/1/9/1563719.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1578358' title='Аритмия / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://picplus.ru/img/1711/15/05d0f570.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1557197' title='Выстрел в пустоту (Главарь) / Shot Caller / 2017 / ПМ / BDRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/9/7/1557197.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1564178' title='Бабушка лёгкого поведения / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/7/8/1564178.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1570558' title='Напарник / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/5/8/1570558.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1579515' title='Мадам / Madame / 2017 / ДБ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://picplus.ru/img/1711/22/d03ca6e5.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1571565' title='Про любовь. Только для взрослых / 2017 / РУ / WEB-DLRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/6/5/1571565.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1576347' title='Троцкий (1-8 серии из 8) / 2017 / РУ / SATRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/4/7/1576347.jpg' alt=''></a>
<a href='/details.php?SbI135km9&amp;id=1569291' title='Оно / It / 2017 / ПМ / HDTVRip' target='_blank'><img src='http://s.kinozal.tv/i/poster/9/1/1569291.jpg' alt=''></a>
`
var re = /<a href='([^']*)'[\s\S]*?'[\s\S]*?<img src='([^']*)'[\s\S]*?<\/a>/g;
while ((m = re.exec(doc)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    console.log(m);
}
```